# How to use nested loop in Vue JS?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Here I Want to use foreach loop inside foreach loop in select option...

```
<select class="form-control" style="width: 100%;" v-model="category_id"  >
<option value="0">Select Main Category</option>
<optgroup v-for='section in categories' v-bind:label="section.name">
    <option  v-for='category in section.categories' :value="category.id">&nbsp;-&nbsp;{{category.category_name}}
    </option>
    <option v-if="" v-for="subCategory in category.sub_categories">&nbsp;&nbsp;--&nbsp; {{subCategory.category_name }}</option>
</optgroup>
```

But its not working ....

Comment: What specifically isn't working? Are you getting an error message? If so, what is the message and when do you get it?

Removing that empty v-if certainly looks like a good place to start. I'd also suggest double checking the v-fors match your data structure - this suggests you have a categories array full of elements which have catagory elements. Is that accurate?

Comment: 'sub_categories' of undefined....
but it work when we put option inside another option field...but thats not how i want..... i  have a categories array full of elements....but its not working...

Comment: <option v-if="" v-for="subCategory in category.sub_categories"> - category is not defined at this point, it is defined in v-for in the option above this, which is closed before you get to this.

Comment: yes  James Clark Developer ....but if we put inside option inside option.then all category and subcategory come into one line so ..

Answer (score 0):

`<option v-if="" v-for="subCategory in category.sub_categories">`

category is not defined at this point, it is defined in `v-for` in the option above this, which is closed before you get to this. so that you will get `sub_categories` of undefined
change like below will work

```
<select class="form-control" style="width: 100%;" v-model="category_id"  >
<option value="0">Select Main Category</option>
<optgroup v-for='section in categories' v-bind:label="section.name">
    <optgroup  v-for='category in section.categories' :value="category.id">&nbsp;-&nbsp;{{category.category_name}}
        <option v-if="" v-for="subCategory in category.sub_categories">&nbsp;&nbsp;--&nbsp; {{subCategory.category_name }}</option>
    </optgroup>
</optgroup>
```

Comment: If we put inside option inside option.then all category and subcategory come into one line..and will selected both at the same time..so thats not how i want ..

Comment: now i think your current question problem is solved.

Comment: Hey is it solved your above questions problem? then accept my answer. Thanks.

Comment: No its not working........now its showing Only section Name......ALthough Thanks